# Valgrind errors that i cant figure out

Tags: c++, valgrind

This is the valgrind error that occurs when i run the program.

```
==137479== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==137479==    at 0x400B50: sdds::Ship::setShipEmpty() (Ship.cpp:25)
==137479==    by 0x400AF2: sdds::Ship::Ship() (Ship.cpp:20)
==137479==    by 0x401181: main (main_prof.cpp:49)
==137479==
==137479== Invalid write of size 1
==137479==    at 0x40097A: sdds::Engine::setEmpty() (Engine.cpp:19)
==137479==    by 0x400B3E: sdds::Ship::setShipEmpty() (Ship.cpp:26)
==137479==    by 0x400AF2: sdds::Ship::Ship() (Ship.cpp:20)
==137479==    by 0x401181: main (main_prof.cpp:49)
==137479==  Address 0x1fff001018 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

My program at the moment is static and not using dynamic memory allocation,
The goal is to create a function to set the variables to a safe empty state. When the object is valid set it accordingly. Here are my functions from Ship.cpp. Similarly, engine.cpp function to set to an empty state is pretty much the same.

```
    Ship::Ship()
    {
        setShipEmpty();
    }
    void Ship::setShipEmpty()
    {
        m_type[0] = '\0';
        for (int i = 0; i < m_engCnt; i++) {
            m_engines[i].setEmpty();
        m_engCnt = 0;
        }}
    
    Ship::Ship(const char* sType, const Engine* engines, int sizeOfEngine)
    {
        if (sType != nullptr && strlen(sType) > 0 && strlen(sType) < TYPE_MAX_SIZE && engines[0].get() > 0 && sizeOfEngine < 10) 
        {
            strcpy(m_type, sType);
            m_engCnt= sizeOfEngine ;

            for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfEngine; i++) {
                m_engines[i] = engines[i];
            }}
        else {
            setShipEmpty();
        }}
```

ship.h file

```
class Ship
    { ...private:
        Engine m_engines[10];
        char m_type[TYPE_MAX_SIZE+1];
        int m_engCnt;
      ....
```

engine.h file

```
const int TYPE_MAX_SIZE = 30;
    
    class Engine
    {
        double m_size;
        char m_type[TYPE_MAX_SIZE+1];
     public:...
```

engine.cpp

```
    void Engine::setEmpty()
    {
        m_type[0] = 0;
        m_size = 0;
    }

    Engine::Engine()
    {
        setEmpty();
    }

    Engine::Engine (const char* type, double size)
    {
        setEmpty();
        strcpy(m_type, type);
        m_size = size;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please add the implementation of `Engine::shipEmpty()`. According to valgrind, this is where the invalid write is happening.

Comment: `m_engCnt = 0; for (int i = 0; i < m_engCnt; i++) {` -- This loop iterates 0 times.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if m_engCnt after the for loop will it execute properly?

Comment: You still haven't posted a [mcve].  We have no idea, where, when, or how you are using these classes, what data you are initializing `Ship` with, etc.  A minimal example would have everything needed for anyone to take the code as-is, not make any changes to it, compile the program, run the program, and reproduce the error.  Also, I bet if you used `std::string` instead of C-style char arrays, maybe you wouldn't have the issues you're seeing now.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind is complaining that you did not set a value for `m_engCnt` yet you are using it in a for loop. Given that `m_engines` is an `Engine[10]`, I suppose you want that loop to just go from 0 to 10.

Two points for improvement:

- Create a default constructor for `Engine` that does whatever `setEmpty` does now. That will allow you to skip the for loop in the `Ship` constructor.
- Even better, switch to a `std::vector<Engine>` so you don't have to manually initialize `Engine`s at the start that you will never use.